# Using JS, backgroundImage won't change for a DIV, but will for the body

Tags: javascript, html, background, refresh

I'm having a beginner problem, that I just can't find an answer to. I know, at least I think I know, my code is correct because it will work when I change the parameters a little bit.

I want to change the background image of a DIV on every refresh of the page, rotating through certain images. The code I am trying to use is this:

```
document.getElementById("random_image").style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/random/'+num+'.jpg)';
```

This does not display anything at all. However, when I change that code to simply:

```
document.body.background = 'url(images/random/'+num+'.jpg)';
```

The code works fine, and displays one of the images on refresh.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: There isn't enough code here to know for sure, but my guess would be that the document.getElementById is being executed before the document is fully constructed, so the element Id "random_image" doesn't exist at the time of execution.

Comment: It might be that there is no element with an id of random_image.

Comment: It should work if your code is ok - http://jsfiddle.net/8Ju85/

Comment: there definitely is an element with that ID. and I'm calling function randomize(); at the end of the body in the .html file.

@NickZimmerman

Comment: @realianstanford What element `#random_image` actually is? Has it content or fixed size?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ38x/) @Teemu

Comment: @realianstanford Another [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2gab6/), seems to work, as well as user3388636's fiddle. Is it possible, that you've more than one element with the same `id` in your real code?

Comment: @Teemu no, just the one ID. also, neither your nor user's code works. I have your code in the head element (my code was your code from the start, but just for the sake of trying, I changed my url to your image) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually it's your image ; ). Do you mean you can't see your avatar at jsFiddle, or the copy-pasted code doesn't work on your page?

Comment: @Teemu no i can see my avatar, but no image shows up with that code.

Comment: You said in a comment: "I'm calling function `randomize();` at the end of the body." If there's an error intercepting the script before this function call?

Comment: @teemu as far as i can tell, no errors.

Comment: Is the random_image have enough height to show the background images??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai yes, the element is of fixed height, and the images are cropped to that specific size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that ended up working for me after some fiddling. Thanks everyone for your attempts to help me, I appreciate it.

```
var totalCount = 4;
function randomize() 
{
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.getElementById("random_image").style.background = 'url(images/random/'+num+'.jpg)';
    /* document.body.background = 'images/random/'+num+'.jpg'; */

}
```